# Using s3 server-side encryption with PHP

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3

I have decide to avail of amazons new server-side encryption with s3, however, I have run into a problem which I am unable to resolve.

I am using the s3 PHP class found here : https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

I had been using this code to put objects originally (and it was working) :

```
     S3::putObjectFile($file, $s3_bucket_name, $file_path, S3::ACL_PRIVATE,
         array(),
    array( 
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$filename",
        "Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream"
            )
);
```

I then did as instructed here : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectPUT.html and added the '**x-amz-server-side​-encryption**' request header. But now when I try to put an object it fails without error.

My new code is :

```
  S3::putObjectFile($file, $s3_bucket_name, $file_path, S3::ACL_PRIVATE,
     array(),
array( 
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$filename",
    "Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream",
        "x-amz-server-side​-encryption" => "AES256"
        )
```

);

Has anybody experimented with this new feature or can anyone see an error in the code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header should be part of the `$metaHeaders` array and not `$requestHeaders` array.

```
S3::putObjectFile($file, $s3_bucket_name, $file_path, S3::ACL_PRIVATE,
     array(
        "x-amz-server-side​-encryption" => "AES256"
     ),
     array( 
       "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$filename",
       "Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream"
     )
);
```

Here's the method definition from the [docs](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject):

```
putObject (mixed $input, 
           string $bucket, 
           string $uri, 
           [constant $acl = S3::ACL_PRIVATE], 
           [array $metaHeaders = array()], 
           [array $requestHeaders = array()])
```

---

You might also consider using the [SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Geoff, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either. I'll do a bit more fiddling around and see if I've overlooked something somewhere.

Comment: @davee - Well in that case, I suspect its because that library hasn't been updated to support the new server side encryption. Why not use the official PHP SDK?

Comment: I thought that it could have been the class too, but then I looked at the source and see the headers are set like so:  

if (is_array($requestHeaders))
foreach ($requestHeaders as $h => $v) $rest->setHeader($h, $v);

so in theory adding the server-side encryption should work. This leads me to think that perhaps amazon hasn't fully implemented the feature across all its systems yet.
Also, unfortunately the code I inherited heavily relies on this class and I don't have the time to update all the code.
I'll see if I can get a response from someone from amazon and post my findings here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We can upload files with encryption using the code following
`$s3->create_object($bucket_name,$destination,array(
                    'acl'=>AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
                    'fileUpload' => $file_local,
                    'encryption'=>"AES256"));`

And you can download latest sdk from [here](http://pear.amazonwebservices.com/get/sdk-latest.zip)

Answer (score 0):

With the official SDK:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = '*** Your File Path ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Upload a file with server-side encryption.
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'               => $bucket,
    'Key'                  => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'           => $filepath,
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
));
```

#### Changing Server-Side Encryption of an Existing Object (Copy Operation)

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key ***';

$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name ***';
$targetKeyname = '*** Your Target Object Key ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Copy an object and add server-side encryption.
$result = $s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'               => $targetBucket,
    'Key'                  => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource'           => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
));
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingPHPSDK.html

Answer (score 0):

With laravel 5+ it can be done easily through filesystems.php config, you don't need to get driver or low level object.

```
's3' => [
  'driver' => 's3',
  'key'    => "Your Key",
  'secret' => "Your Secret",
  'region' => "Bucket Region",
  'bucket' => "Bucket Name",
  'options' => [
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
  ]
],
//Code
$disk->put("filename", "content", "public"); // will have AES for file
```