# How can I use Storage::disk('s3')->put() when my s3's x-amz-server-side-encryption is AES256 at Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

RT.

This is my s3's filesystem configure:

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

And this is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~2.0",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "raven/raven": "0.12.*"
    },
```

And this is my s3's bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*****bucket_name*****/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Yes, I used `"s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"` as my PutObject's condition,  but I wanna use like this code:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('test.log','123');
```

But when I run it, I will got response like this:

```
[Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception]                                                                                                                                    
Error executing "HeadObject" on "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/****bucket_name****/test.log"; AWS HTTP error: Client error response [url]https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/****bucket_name****/test.log [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden  (client): 403 Forbidden (Request-ID: 39C30C8512E5ED16) -

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]                                                                                                                     
Client error response [url] https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/****bucket_name****/test.log [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden
```

So, how can I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: At last, we modified our configure permission, the problem has been resolved, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681752/using-s3-server-side-encryption-with-php

Answer (score 7):

*(Laravel 5.3)* If your bucket policy requires server side encryption for all objects, rather than access the S3 driver and pass arguments to that, I was able to universally enable S3 SSE by setting it as an option in the configuration:

config/filesystems.php

```
...

's3' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
                'options' => [
                    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
                ]
            ],

...
```

With the ServerSideEncryption option set in the configuration, I am able to make method calls on the "disk" directly.

```
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->putFileAs($prefix, new File($path), $filename);
```

Comment: this is the right answer for encryption to a whole bucket

Answer (score 2):

If you retrieve the S3 driver you can supply arguments:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->put('filename', 'randomdata', ['ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256']);
```